# Change the spawn point for LAN players in a single player map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Using Minecraft 1.3, a single player map can be opened up for LAN play.

**How do you change where other players will spawn?**

I know how to change my *own* spawn point (by using a bed), but how can I change where other players on the LAN will spawn when they join in?

The original place I spawned in this world is a very long walk from where I am now, and my wife wants to join in without having to walk the whole way there.

Comment: Can't be that far of a walk. Just tape down your forward arrow key and go watch a movie ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't do this without using a world editing program. Just have your wife join, teleport her, and have her sleep in a bed.

You can teleport like this:
`/tp [wife's username] [your username]`

Answer (score 7):

Edit the spawn coordinates in the `level.dat` file for your World. You can use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to do this very easily.

As of Minecraft 1.7.2 you can use the `/setworldspawn` command to do this without using external programs.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to set a new spawn in smp